# Analysis Design Diagrams and Domain Models

Tags: uml, modeling, class-diagram, domain-model, conceptual

As I know analysis design diagrams and domain models are not completely same. Whats the differencies between them?

edit: I want to add to them "conceptual class diagrams" also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain model is about [topics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_model). How the subject is structured?

The Analysis design is about [functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_Analysis_and_Design_Technique). How the structure works? (not so good term, saying design we normally think on structures)

They complement each other.

Answer (score 1):

This question is pretty much the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265491/what-is-the-difference-between-a-domain-class-diagram-and-a-design-class-diagram/21285190#21285190), for which I have given an answer.