# Are field types in class diagram obligatory?

Tags: language-agnostic, uml, class-diagram

When specifying class fields in class diagram you can provide their types, e.g.:

```
- name : string
- age : int
```

Same with methods:

```
+ getName() : string
```

You can also omit the type if the method doesn't have/return one:

```
+ ClassName()   // constructor
+ performCleanup()   // returns void
```

1. But what if the diagram only presents some example fields (i.e. presenting the design pattern idea) and the concrete type is unimportant? Do I pick any type at random for the field or should I omit the type?

   - sampleField1 : int   // arbitrary type
   - sampleField2   // no type specified

---

2. Also, is providing field types obligatory in general? Should I always do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** You can omit the type and it is not obligatory, sometimes you even don't know the exact types or you just don't care, e.g. in [uml-diagrams.org: Library Domain Model, UML Class Diagram Example](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/library-domain-uml-class-diagram-example.html)

---

[UML 2.4.1 Infrastructure specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.4.1/) says:

> ...10.2.5 Property
>
> ...**A property** is a typed element that **represents an attribute** of a class...
>
> ...10.1.5 TypedElement
>
> ...A typed element is a kind of named element that represents elements with types...
>
> ...Elements with types are instances of TypedElement. A typed element **may optionally have no type**...
>
> [image]

See also:

- [What is the difference between a domain class diagram and a design class diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265491/what-is-the-difference-between-a-domain-class-diagram-and-a-design-class-diagram)