# difference between business class diagram, domain class diagram, design class diagram

Tags: uml

I can't seem to understand the differences between a domain class diagram, a business class diagram and a design class diagram?

i've read that domain and business are concetpual models while design is a logical model.

does this mean that a design class diagram is used by programmers to use this a base for creating the ui/interfaces?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between a domain class diagram and a design class diagram?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21265491/what-is-the-difference-between-a-domain-class-diagram-and-a-design-class-diagram)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is the contents of the diagrams. They are all class diagrams. Business and Domain are more or less two words for the same thing (I prefer the latter).

The domain diagram holds rather abstract classes describing the domain. You abstract them from concrete business objects (like some paper, persons or machines being used) mainly focusing on their attributes.

A design class diagram contains classes which have been created based on a former system analysis / use case synthesis.

Comment: Could you recommend a systematic approach for extracting business class diagrams

Comment: @Fabiana There are thick books about that topic. I can only forward you to Google here...

Comment: Do you recommend a specific site, online article, etc? Not all sites are good or have accurate information

Comment: I need to be honest: no real recommendation. I did a quick google and nothing really jumped on me. I learned it the hard way in many years and that's probably the best way. I remember that once I started with the ICONIX approach (some 20 years ago). No Idea whether Doug Rosenberg still is at it, but that got me really going. Still it took me several years to come to solid stand point. Also Bittner/Spence about Use Case Modeling is a must read.